# Pattern matching exact word and delete in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using Perl to clean up a raw text file which contains some odd characters like the following:

```
printableNNH=0A=0A    =0A=0A=0A    Event Registration Request=0A=0A ...
```

There are many occurances of **=0A** in the file which I have to get rid of. They occure in random sets of like above where there is an example of 2 and 3.

I am using the following line in my Perl script to eliminate there characters:

```
tr/=0A//d; #remove =0A
```

**That works but it also removes the zeros (0) from all telephone numbers and other content containing 0s.**

Can anyone advise on pattern matching an exact substring and deleting it?

Comment: It should also remove all occurrences of `=` and `A`. See `perldoc perlop` under "Quote and Quote-like Operators."

Comment: Are you sure you want to *remove* them? It looks to me like an encoding of special characters so that the whole data is on one line. If `=0A` = `\n`, you could run the substitution `s/=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/chr hex $1/eg` to decode the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr///` is not a regular expression: It will (with the `-d` modifier) substitute *single characters* with *zero characters*.

In your case, using `tr/=0A//` will replace every occurrence of `=` `0` *and* `A` with nothing.

`s///` however, is a substitution operator, which will substitute a regular expression with a specified character string - in your case zero characters.

Thus, use:

```
open my $input, '<', 'in.txt' or die "$!";

while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    s/=0A//g;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's/=0A//g' inFile > outFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following if you only want to remove `=0A` and not `=`,`0` or `A`

```
$string=~s/=0A//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cds
> y/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cds
>
> Transliterates all occurrences of the characters found in the search list with the corresponding character in the replacement list.

Instead of replacing all occurrences of `=0A`, `tr` replaces all occurrences of `=`, `0`, *and* `A`:

```
perl -we '$_ = "foo=0AbAr0"; tr/=0A//d; print'
```

Prints:

```
foobr
```

Instead, you should use `s/pattern/replacement/`, e.g.

```
perl -we '$_ = "foo=0AbAr0"; s/=0A//g; print'
```

Prints:

```
foobAr0
```

The `g` modifier performs the replacement globally, i.e. for every occurrence in a line.